# How do I logout from a non-registered account?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, user-accounts, privacy, anonymous

I have a registered StackOverflow account which I normally log into using OpenID.  Recently I logged out in order to post a question anonymously (supplying a fake name and of my secondary email addresses).

The problem now is that I'm logged in to StackOverflow as this "dummy" user, unable to see a way to log out.  The top menu normally has a "logout" link, but when you aren't fully registered this link is replaced with "register".  There is no "logout" link for me. :(

So..

- When logged out there is a "login" link.
- When logged in there is a "logout" link.
- When "logged in" with an unregistered account, there is only a "register" link (no "logout").

Comment: So register and then sign out.  *Duh.*

Comment: @HilariousComedyPesto Nice joke... thanks lol

Answer (score 21):

We do that to prevent people from irrevocably destroying unregistered accounts, as they are 100% browser cookie based.

You can probably guess the URL if you really need to do this:

/users/logout

Comment: This works perfectly, yet this approach surprises me ...

Comment: "unregistered" and "account" are contradictory. Bad design. Unregistered should mean unregistered, not "account without credentials".

Answer (score 10):

Just delete the cookies your browser has saved for the site in question... That's all there is to keep you "logged in".

Comment: Or maybe just move them elsewhere for the time being. Otherwise you won't be able to use that same account again.

Comment: Note: Firefox 65 "lies" to me when I look at the cookies for this site by saying "None".

Comment: Use the dev tools -> storage tab, @AaronDigulla - it'll show you all the .stackexchange.com cookies too.