# Logging out of Stack Overflow or any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, user-accounts, logout, unregistered-users

I want to log out of Stack Overflow or any Stack Exchange site, but always it shows me logged in!

How do I log out of this site?

**Note:** I have yet to register; the site currently always shows my name and default email.
I wish to log out so that I may start a new session!

Comment: See: [How do I logout from a non-registered account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9392/how-do-i-logout-from-a-non-registered-account)

Comment: Open the Stack Exchange Dropdown menu from the top left. It opens with a list of its domains. The current domain will be listed at the top with chat, blog and logout options. You can log yourself out with that link. Hope this helps.

Comment: Shows there is clearly something wrong if so many people have to search and learn how to logout of this site. It should be obvious without having to look for it.

Comment: agreed.  The logout link is buried in a menu.  I had to come here to be told where to find it.

Comment: yeah, and even after clicking logout, you have to click logout on a button on its own page as well?!?    couldn't you just program that code into the logout link? do you REALLY not want people logging out or what?

Comment: The good 5 min I searched for logout and ended deleting the relevant cookies were the 5 min the cafeteria -- together with my lunch -- closed prior. >:(

Comment: This isn't a duplicate; this question is about registered users, who do have an explicitly provided interface that a lot of people ask about because it's hard to find. The other question is about the fact that unregistered users don't get that same interface.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel From this question: "I have yet to register".  Looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Laurel but the question was answered in a way that ignores this; the title doesn't mention it; and every question that comes from registered users gets duped here.

Answer (score 32):

### As of 2017-03-20

For registered users, the 'logout' option is on the drop-down menu from the right-most icon on the menu bar:

[image: drop down menu open with log out link highlighted]

#### Without a registered account

Posting as a guest creates a sort of dummy account, based on a browser cookie. In these cases, the logout link is deliberately suppressed. See [How do I logout from a non-registered account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9392) for details.

### Historically

This interface may change in the future, as it has before:

#### As of 2014-03-14

There is a logout link accessible from the black top bar; activate the 'Stack Exchange' drop down menu and the 'logout' link should be beside the entry for the site you're currently accessing (along with 'blog' and 'chat').

#### When the question was asked (2009-09-23)

Simply click the logout button at the top of the page.

Comment: This link you are talking about DNE..

Comment: @Erik: yes, I guess you are right; in the 21 months or so since the question was asked, the answer has changed.  But the question is closed as a duplicate of another.  Follow that if you want to find out what the modern answer is - or at least bug the people who answered over there.

Comment: It didn't logout completely why ?

Comment: @keshav: Things have changed dramatically since this was written. In particular, the top bar no longer shows a logout option for me (or maybe they don't want to let me log out). Go look for other, more recent 'how to log out?' questions; there are a number listed in the 'related' list to the right.