# Please, let me log out nice-and-easy, Stack Exchange

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid, logout

Every time I log out Stack Exchange by clicking: Stack Exchange->Log out->Log out (yellow button). I actually get logged out.

The problem is, next time I click Log in, I’ll be logged in with the previous credentials, no questions ask.

My question is almost exactly the same as this:

[How to log out completely on stackexchange sites using OpenID without closing my browser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92326/how-to-log-out-completely-on-stackexchange-sites-using-openid-without-closing-my)

However there were no satisfactory answers since what I want is not a tricky, computer expert answer. I just want a simple, one-or-two button pressed and goodbye, see ya next time.

And this [Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924/tell-me-how-to-log-out-of-stack-exchange-openid) nice question, has no single answer.

I actually googled for “log out from stack exchange” and then moved through the links provided, but no satisfactory answers. Some examples are:

Example 1: [How can I log out of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23102/how-can-i-log-out-of-stack-overflow)

Example 2: [how to logout from stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294881/how-to-logout-from-stackoverflow)

Example 3: [How do I log out of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645233/how-do-i-log-out-of-stack-overflow)

PS: I’ve tried to check the “Log out to all devices” checkbox, still nothing.

EDIT: I’ve Logged in using Stack Exchange ID, nor Google, Facebook or other logging credentials provider.

Comment: I’ve used the link https://openid.stackexchange.com/ and it works. But it is so annoying and definitely not user-friendly.

Answer (score 6):

> The problem is, next time I click Log in, I’ll be logged in with the previous credentials, no questions ask.

That's because you are still logged into your OpenID provider, e.g. Google.

If you want to avoid that, you need to log out explicitly from the provider, each offering their own way to logout. For example, to logout from Stack Exchange OpenID provider, click "logout" [here](https://openid.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not logged in to google. I actually logged in using Stack Exchange ID.

Comment: @physicsrev same. So just logout from the provider itself, which for SE OpenID happens to be https://openid.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Oded I see that you edited your answer and I think it's quite nice now. Still the point is: Is there a button or link in the Stack Exchange logout page directing me to the proper ID Provider logout page? Am I missing it?. My question is not only to be forgotten, but to do it as a **dummy**.

Comment: @physicsrev - what if you have 5 different providers you linked to your Stack Exchange account? Do we give you 5 links?

Comment: To be honest, @physicsrev, I don't really understand your concern. When you click "log in", you are presented with the [login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ3Xh.png) - where you need to select how to login. We don't automatically log you in.

Comment: @oded Let me explain: It's not about logging IN. It's about logging OUT in such a way that in my next log in, I should be asked to provide my Username and password again. For example if one logs in with stack exchange’s log in ID, when logging out there should be a bottom saying: “To logout from your login provider, please click [here] (https://openid.stackexchange.com/user)” and it directs the user to the link you provided in your answer.

Comment: @physicsrev - again, not clear to me what your use case is. When you log out, we don't ever automatically log you in (which seems to be what you are describing). You log out, you are logged out. When you then click "log in" we ask you to... log in. What exactly is broken there for you?

Comment: As I asked before, @physicsrev - what do you expect to happen if you have 5 different providers attached to your account (you can add as many as you want and we have many users that have multiple such setups)?

Comment: I  have tried what you just suggested. I was asked for my email address and password: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptrsc.png - are you using a browser extension that automatically puts those in for you, @physicsrev ?

Comment: @Oded At the bottom of the LOGOUT PAGE of Stack Exchange there is the following message: *”If you're on a shared computer, remember to log out of your Open ID provider (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange OpenID, etc.) as well”*.  What the page doesn’t do is to explain how to do it. HOW to log out from the Open ID provider.

Comment: I’m not the only one pointing this out. Check the second link I provided and he point exactly the same thing. The solution he provides is the same as mine. Make the *”If you're on a shared computer, remember to log out of your Open ID provider (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange OpenID, etc.) as well”* message as link to the correct Open ID provider. Stack Exchange must know which ID provider was used to log in, and also (I think) it should provide for better ways of terminate that. At least for your own Open ID, which would have been direct the user to the link in you answer.

Comment: @Oded I tried to use a different browser. It continues...

Comment: Are you telling me that when you click "log in" in the login page, without entering an email and password you get logged in?

Comment: @Oded Yes I do.

Comment: And this happens to you when you login here or physics, @physicsrev ?

Comment: Usually everywhere. Physics, Mathematics or here. This just happens if I log out by following just the "Normal" way. On Internet Explorer or in Google Chrome (the browsers I'm using. I have no extensions install in those (other than the default ones). The only way to prevent it is by force browsing into https://openid.stackexchange.com log out there and then log out the “normal” way.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why this is a problem? When you are logged out of the sites, you are logged out of the sites.

Comment: Two reasons. First, sometimes I use a shared computer and I'd like to have an easy way to terminate the session without have to remember on force browsing into some random page or link.
Second, I have an alternative user ID for discussion of different issues then those people in my network expects. For example a question about the workplace or personal issues I’d like to make those on a different persona. The problem is when trying to change from one user to another is a bit annoying when it automatically opens the last one, but we want a different one.

Comment: But what you are describing just doesn't happen on the Q&A sites. When you click the "Log In" button, you are required to put in an email and password.

Comment: No. It doesn't requires. This is what in saying...

Comment: And I am telling you that if you go to the physics site login page, you are required (or here on meta). What Q&A site are you going to that this isn't the case for, @physicsrev ?

Comment: How can I explain to you what is happening.

For example on Windows live email, when loggin In, there is a check button “**Keep me signed in**”, therefore two things may happen:

1. If you don’t check it, no matter if one terminates session by clicking on “**Terminate Session**” or just closes the tab/browser. The next time he tries to log in, he will be asked for the login credentials (username and password);

Comment: 2. If one checks it and then just close the tab/browser without terminating session by clicking “**Terminate Session**”, the next time he tries to access his email it just logs in WITHOUT requiring for the login credentials.

With Stack Exchange no matter if you just close the tab/browser or follows Stack Exchange->Log out->Log out (yellow button), it behaves like the second option. It means, I’ll be automatically logged in the next time I navigate to the page or click log in. I won’t be asked for an email or password.

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that we can't control sessions of open ID providers like Google and Facebook - that's just not under our control, and is fundamental to how open ID works. Windows live email - belongs to Microsoft - it is a single site and the authentication it uses is all under Microsoft control. It is a very different situation, @physicsrev

Comment: @Oded What I mean is that when a user Logs out by following **Stack Exchange->Log out->Log out (yellow button)**, He should be logged out. These commands should be the equivalent to **Terminate Session** on Windows live, as I said before. You guys, may create a Cookie or something in your servers, with a **flag** informing that user logged out. That’s it. No matter if logged out on Google or something else.

Comment: @physicsrev - that is exactly what we do. We log you out. We terminate the session. What you don't understand is what happens when you click "log in" again. We ask the OpenId provider - "Who is this person?" (we don't know - you are logged out). If you are not logged in to your provider - they ask you to log in. Next, once you are logged in (or if already logged in), they check - did this person authorise us to give Stack Exchange their identity? Given you have done so in the past, they find that you did and give us the identity. At that point we check that - figure out it is your account...

Comment: ...and you are logged in. Transparently. This is why we always recommend to log out of your open Id provider as well when using a shared computer. If you use such a computer and log into gmail, you would log out of gmail before, right? That's exactly what we recommend to do.