# How to unsubscribe stackoverflow?

Tags: support, unsubscribe

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/delete-my-account)
>   [How do I logout from a non-registered account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9392/how-do-i-logout-from-a-non-registered-account)

I cannot see any links in the interface, or any help in the FAQ : how to unsubscribe stackoverflow ?

Comment: What do you mean by "unsubscribe"? Log out? Or are you talking about email notifications?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/delete-my-account

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>, I believe.