# Security feature?

Tags: support, login, security

I recently discovered that I don't need to enter my password to log into Serverfault after successfully logging out.  I'm not sure this is as secure as intended.

Steps to repeat (using Firefox 25.0.1)
- Log in using stackexchange credentials
- Log out
- Log in using the stackexchange button without credentials
- Successfully logged in without typing anything...

Is this just me?

Comment: You did not log out from your OpenID provider.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I logout from a non-registered account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9392)

Comment: Tasty, Tasty Cookies.

Comment: Ick, dupe link fail. I'll find the right one.

Comment: Final attempt: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't logging out of Stack Overflow log me out of Gmail?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41094)

Comment: That's.. Kind of a duplicate... I guess.

Comment: I was going to hunt for a dupe to help Martijn save face, but ended up  knee-deep in OpenID questions.

Answer (score 3):

Like Martijn mentioned in his [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209765/security-feature#comment671874_209765), you must have not logged out of your OpenID provider (StackExchange, Google, etc.). Thus, when you logout from ServerFault, it's just ServerFault that you logout from. Meaning, when you try to re-login using StackExchange credentials, the cookies (session login data) on your OpenId provider site are retrieved by the OpenId provider to which you have granted authority to log you into ServerFault.